# How to parse array of date string into Dates in moment

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I've a array of dates in a string format.

I wanted to parse the array of dates and pass that new date value into `addDates`

i tied `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`, but not working its give an error `Conversion from "undefined" format not allowed on jQuery.multiDatesPicker`. Please help

```
var newDateArray: any[];

    "Dates": [
      "2018-01-01",
      "2018-01-03",
      "2018-01-05"     
    ]

      for(let i=0; i<= this.newDateArray.length; i++) {
        let date = moment(i).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        this.newDateArray.push(i)
      }

 $(this.eInput).multiDatesPicker({ 
        addDates: [this.newDateArray],
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" 
  });
```

Comment: Where in your code are you using moment?

Comment: updated my code, i've added only partial code

Comment: Try this `let date = moment(this.newDateArray[i]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 `

Comment: i still get this error `Conversion from "undefined" format not allowed on jQuery.multiDatesPicker`

Comment: `addDates` should be in this format `addDates: ['10/14/2018', '02/19/2018', '01/14/2018', '11/16/2018'],`

Comment: You want to select the dates,which in Dates?

Comment: @arunkumar You are getting "undefined" because you are passing the index in to moment, or in Hassan's suggest an undefined value since `this.newDateArray` is empty on the first pass. Please see my answer below to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code. Your dates declaration isn't proper javascript, although I'm assuming you copied this from within an object or something. You are also iterating over the empty list rather than your date list and only passing the index in to moment. Change your for loop to this:

```
var newDateArray: any[];

dates: [
    "2018-01-01",
    "2018-01-03",
    "2018-01-05"     
]

// iterate over the dates list from above
for(let i = 0; i <= dates.length; i++) {
    // pass the date at index i into moment
    let date = moment(dates[i]).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log("date", date);
    // add this new date to the newDateArray
    this.newDateArray.push(date)
    console.log("newDateArray", this.newDateArray);
}
```